# How to use ReactiveUI's RoutedViewHost with Xamarin Forms Shell?

Tags: xamarin, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI and want to use Shell (Xamarin Forms 4) because it gives other options including flyout menu etc. because of how routing works with Xamarin Forms, it is either going to be Shell or RoutedViewHost.

I even attempted to replace my RoutedViewHost to use Shell, but Shell has few problems of its own including the inability to clear navigation stack.

I couldn't find any example or working example where ReactiveUI works with Xamarin Forms's Shell, is there a way that I can leverage RoutedViewHost along with Shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time we do not support Shell with ReactiveUI's Routing.  We are working with the Xamarin.Forms team to get a better understanding of how we can plug into the Shell infrastructure.  Shell is a completely different approach to navigation than the pre existing ReactiveUI Routing and Xamarin.Forms Navigation.

The following is a repository where we are working on support for ReactiveUI.

https://github.com/PureWeen/ReactShell